# How to determine a NSInteger is in the NSRange?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example,a `NSInteger` 8 ,is in the `NSRange` (4,10).
I have checked `NSRange` API and didn't find one method to determine it.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139085/how-can-i-use-nsrange-with-integers-to-simplify-my-code

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5223205/1226963

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test to see if number is in range using Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223039/how-to-test-to-see-if-number-is-in-range-using-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSLocationInRange`:

```
NSInteger num = 8;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(4, 10); // 4 - 14
if (NSLocationInRange(num, range)) {
    // num in range
}
```